# Fourier series of dirac delta

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $f \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is it true that
$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \sum_{z\in \mathbb{}{Z^n}} \int_\mathbb{R^n} f\left( \frac{x}{\epsilon} \right) e^{iz (x-a\epsilon)} dx = f(a)$$

Formally, if we put the sum inside and use the formal series representation of dirac delta $\delta (x-a) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\sum_{z\in \mathbb{}{Z^n}} e^{iz (x-a)}$ then it seems we get the result. But this is not rigorous.

Comment: say that $n = 1$, what is $S(\mathbb{R})$ ? and for the ($1$-periodic) Dirac delta you have to define it as a distribution : $\langle \delta_a, f \rangle = f(a)$ for every $1$-periodic function $f$ being continuous at $a$. then $\langle \delta_a, f \rangle  = \langle \sum_n e^{2 i \pi n (x-a)}, f \rangle =  \sum_n  \langle e^{2 i \pi n (x-a)}, f \rangle= \sum_n \int_0^1 e^{2 i \pi n (x-a)} f(x) dx =  \sum_n e^{2 i \pi n}  \int_0^1 e^{-2 i \pi n a} f(x) dx = f(a)$ by the Fourier series theorem

Comment: $S(R^n)$ is the space of Schwartz functions. They are smooth and of rapid decay.

Comment: yes I know, I didn't see the $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}$) your formula is not true, periodize $f(x)$ you'll go back to the Fourier series (and you'll get the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Poisson_summation_formula) )

Comment: The result you have written is false unless $f\equiv 0$.  Pick $n=1$: the LHS is then periodic in $a$ because $\exp(iz(x-a))=\exp(iz(x-a-2m\pi))$ for integer $m$ and all integer $z$.  A periodic function with period $2\pi$, call it $g(a)$, which is in $\mathscr{S}$ is zero since its limits at $\pm\infty$ are required to be $0$ (that's an aspect of being in $\mathscr{S}$) and so $0=\lim_{n\to\infty} g(a+2n\pi)=g(a)$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I would reconsider the question and edit...

Comment: the most important part was that : $\sum_{n-\infty}^\infty e^{2 i \pi n x}$ is not the Fourier series of the Dirac delta but of the $1$-periodized Dirac delta $\sum_{n-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-n)$. (in $\mathbb{R}^N$ it works exactly the same)

Answer (score 0):

The integral equals $\epsilon^n\widehat{f}(\epsilon z) e^{-ia\epsilon z}$, and thus the sum can be viewed as a Riemann sum for $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\widehat{f}(t)e^{-iat}\, dt=f(a)$.

Comment: Actually, the original question was proving convergence of the Riemann sum. Is there a reference for this? Or how can it be proven? Thank you.

Comment: Since we are dealing with a very well behaved integrand, we can interpret the integral as a Riemann integral, and then it's *defined* as the limit of its Riemann sums (here, you probably also want to approximate the integral over $\mathbb R^n$ by one over a large bounded region, which is possible because $\widehat{f}$ decays rapidly).